# Families of continuous functions with non-continuous derivatives

Tags: functions, derivatives, continuity

What families of functions have the property of being continuous yet having a non-continuous derivative? And how many of these families are there?

$$f(x) = \sqrt[n]{x}$$

when "n" is an odd number and not equal to 1 is an example (derivative is always undefined at x=0).

Comment: What is the definition of "family". I don't know of any strict definition. If "family" just means "set" that basically means that the answer to your second question is $2^{\text{number of such functions}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a$ is a **real number such that $a\neq0$**. Each function $f_{a}$ : $[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f_{a}(x) =
\begin{cases}
ax  & \text{if $x >0,$} \\
0 & \text{if $x =0$,}
\end{cases}
$$ is such that
$$
f'_{a}(x) =
\begin{cases}
a  & \text{if $x >0,$} \\
0 & \text{if $x =0$,}
\end{cases}
$$ and each function $f'_{a}(\cdot)$ is not continuous at $x=0$. The family
$$
E=\bigcup_{a \in \mathbb{R}}f_{a}
$$ is infinite: $|E|=|\mathbb{R}|$.

Answer (score 1):

Piece-wise continuous function that aren't differentiable at transition points are another (e.g. $f(x)=|x|$)